# SQL Schema Compare on Visual Studio 2013, Is there any way to compare more than 2 databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-schema

I did a schema compare on two database within different servers using VS 2013 Schema compare tool, and it's working fine.

I would like to do it on multiple database for each servers.

Is there any way to compare multiple database at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand the Multiple Database concept correctly, but what i understand from your question is:

if you want to compare more than two databases with each other in a single view, No you can not, you can compare only two databases with each other.

if you want to compare multiple databases to one master copy then yes you can, you can open schema compare in as many tabs as you want and in each schema compare you can select the source as the master copy and the target required to compare. and then you can compare all together simultaneously.

it s regardless of whether the databases are on the same server or different.